# Regex to delete lines between double square brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

Have a document with multiple multi-line sections that look like:

```
[[
this
is
an
example
]]
```

Would be great to have a regex statement that could iterate through the document and remove all the lines between the bracket sets, leaving one blank line between like

```
[[

]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find

> \[\[(.*?\r\n)*?\]\]

replace with:

> \[\[\r\n\]\]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[\[\R\K.+?(?=\R]])`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[\[        # 2 opening square brackets
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
.+?         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    ]]          # 2 closing square bracket
)           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]